# Automatically change interface colors for normal(visual) vs input mode

Tags: insert-mode, visual-mode, colorscheme

I have found a related question here:
[Automatically set the 'number' option in Vim when entering Ex mode, set 'nonumber' in visual mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11015/automatically-set-the-number-option-in-vim-when-entering-ex-mode-set-nonumbe)

Still I am not sure that I can follow those explanations to achieve what I want.
So here is what I want to achieve:

For **normal (and visual) mode**, I've set up a color bar, for example here
I [ab]use the foldcolumn to indicate that I am in visual mode (*see on the left a blue vertical bar*):

[image]

Now if I go into **insert mode** I want it to change the color (*now the bar is gray as if it is gone*):

[image]

I want this to set up a strong visual feedback which helps 
to always see in which mode I am currently.
Sometimes I start to input text when I am in normal or visual 
mode and this results in running a lot of Vim's commands.

So how can I make that the color changes automatically in run-time when switching from insert to normal mode and back?
Here I use is foldcolumn, but it can be something else with similar effect to this.

VIM 7.4, Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `InsertEnter` and `InsertLeave` autocmd events. For example, say I [ab]used the `cursorline` setting instead of the foldcolumn:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * set cursorline
autocmd InsertLeave * set nocursorline
```

[image]
[image]

So whatever it is you do to change the colour of the foldcolumn (`hi FoldColumn ctermbg=blue`?), put those as the commands after the `autocmd InsertEnter *` and `autocmd InsertLeave *`.

This is easier for the insert mode than other modes, since there are autocmd events for entering and leaving insert mode, but not for normal, visual, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Muru's answer, here is what I made:
In colorscheme file set the default color for foldcolumn:

```
hi FoldColumn  guifg=#C7C8B8  guibg=#DACBAD
```

Then in **vimrc** file enable foldcolumn (set foldcolumn=2) and add color settings on **InsertEnter** and **InsertLeave** events:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * hi FoldColumn guifg=#C7C8B8 guibg=#E6E5DC
autocmd InsertLeave * hi FoldColumn guifg=fg guibg=#DACBAD
```

::
Normal mode:

[image]

::
Insert mode:

[image]